# I am trying to create an animation using two values: even and odd. Yet, even when these values are correctly logged, the image does not change. Why?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an animation of a goomba walking. Unfortunately, the image is merely static.

```
<img src="https://www.spriters-resource.com/resources/sheets/49/52570.png?updated=1635821170" id="sprite" width='0' height='0'>
<canvas></canvas>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0px !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
    const img = document.getElementById("sprite");
    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    let number = 'even';
    let usage = 0;
    function useframes() {
        requestAnimationFrame(useframes);
        if (usage < 10) {
            usage += 1;
            console.log(usage);
        }
        if (usage >= 10 && number == 'even') {
            number = 'odd';
            usage = 0;
            console.log(number);
        }else if(usage >= 10 && number == 'odd') {
            number = 'even';
            usage = 0;
            console.log(number);
        }
    }
    useframes();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const pattern = c.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
        if (number == 'even') {
            c.rect(18, 16, 16, 16);
        }else if(number == 'odd') {
            c.rect(0, 16, 16, 16);
        }
        c.fillStyle = pattern;
        c.fill();
    });
</script>
```

I tried to setInterval and requestAnimationFrame and both of these did not work, with the static image. I used console.log to make sure that the values were properly changed, yet even though the values are changing, the image is the same.

So I tried using drawImage() instead of rect(). Unfortunately, the result was the same.

```
<img src="https://www.spriters-resource.com/resources/sheets/49/52570.png?updated=1635821170" id="sprite" width='0' height='0'>
<canvas></canvas>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0px !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
    const img = document.getElementById("sprite");
    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    let number = 'even';
    let usage = 0;
    function useframes() {
        requestAnimationFrame(useframes);
        if (usage < 10) {
            usage += 1;
        }
        if (usage >= 10 && number == 'even') {
            number = 'odd';
        }
        if (usage >= 10 && number == 'odd') {
            number = 'even';
        }
    }
    useframes();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => {
        if (number == 'even') {
            c.drawImage(img, 18, 16, 16, 16, 100, 100, 16, 16);
        }else if(number == 'odd') {
            c.drawImage(img, 0, 16, 16, 16, 100, 100, 16, 16);
        }
    });
</script>
```

I even tried to remove the image onload entirely, but that rendered absolutely nothing. I assumed that the issue was coming from the fact that the image was already loaded.

Comment: your code has too many mistakes. i understand you are trying to shift the image from `{18, 16}` to `{0, 16}` but why don't you clearable canvas?
about the fact that the `requestAnimationFrame` at the top of the function will still work but that's due to a single-threaded effect and is logically wrong (acceptable)

more importantly why are you changing the `number`, `usage` variables every iteration? this frequency is 60hz which means each position will have 30hz almost at the same time you don't even redraw the image

Comment: It was purposefully meant to be in the same position, kind of like a gif. That is why clearRect was not used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `c.drawImage(...)` invocation inside the animation loop. Otherwise, it is only called once. Also, you need to reset the `usage` variable back to `1` once it hits `10`.

```html
<img
  src="https://www.spriters-resource.com/resources/sheets/49/52570.png?updated=1635821170"
  id="sprite"
  width="0"
  height="0"
/>
<canvas></canvas>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px !important;
  }
</style>
<script>
 const img = document.getElementById("sprite");
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  let number = "even";
  let usage = 0;

  img.addEventListener("load", () => {
    function useframes() {
      requestAnimationFrame(useframes);
      if (usage < 10) {
        usage += 1;
      }
      
      if (usage >= 10 && number == "even") {
        number = "odd";
        usage = 1;
      } else if (usage >= 10 && number == "odd") {
        number = "even";
        usage = 1;
      }

      if (number == "even") {
        c.drawImage(img, 18, 16, 16, 16, 100, 100, 16, 16);
      } else if (number == "odd") {
        c.drawImage(img, 0, 16, 16, 16, 100, 100, 16, 16);
      }
    }
    useframes();
  });
</script>
```